# Access static function from an extended class within an API call

Tags: php, api

I don't know if this is possible, but it would certainly by the easiest solution to the dilemma I am currently facing.

I have class that is loaded via API - we'll call it "my_service"

```
'my_service' => getClient('Class_Services')
```

This loads my_service which which extends my_base

```
<?php

// class_services.php
class Class_Services
    extends my_base
```

Within my_base, I have a static function that I use to get objects

```
public static function findById($id) {//blah}
```

my_base is NOT able to be loaded through the API like I load my_service.

How can I call findById through my_service, since it extends my_base? I thought I might be able to get it with "forward_static_call", but I am having troubles with that one. I've also tried to access findById with the following lines:

```
$obj = $api->my_service->findById($id);

$obj = $api->my_service::findById($id);

$obj = $api->my_service->my_base::findById($id);

$obj = my_base::findById($id);
```

... but none of these work. If this is possible, will someone please help point me in the right direction?

Comment: What exactly does `$api->my_service` contain at this point? Is it a true `Client_Services` object or some abstraction? `var_dump($api->my_service);`

Comment: It just contains variables and functions that are used for logging, mostly. But in a couple of the functions, my_base::findById($id) is used. Since I can't load my_base, and it's extended by my_service, I was hoping that I could access findById through my_service, somehow

Comment: You can't extend a class until after you define the class. So if you can't load `my_base`, you can't define `Class_Services`.

Comment: my_base is defined and is in use within the code. When I say I cannot load it, I mean I cannot load it through the API the same way I load my_service, because my_base is not accessible that way (i.e. 'my_base' => getClient('Base_Class') does not work)

Comment: If it's a static function you should be able to call it as `my_base::findById($id)`.

Comment: You don't need to go through an object to call a static method.